# Plot isn't showing the full range of my function

Tags: plotting

I have this function that I want to graph

```
V[x_] = (1 (1 - E^(-9.8 x)))
```

But when I graph it it shows a function that is not correct

[image]

It should pass through origin.

If anyone could help, I would be much obliged.

Comment: You don't need to use `Show`

Answer (score 7):

To your question itself, in executing `Plot` you have specified the domain (`{x, 0, 5}`), but not the range. So, `Plot` tries to show the most interesting parts of the function. To show everything, you change the range, you need to add the option [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.htm), e.g.

```
Plot[V[x] (1 (1 - E^(-9.8 x))), {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

With regards to your code itself, a couple of points. First, [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) does not need to be wrapped in `Show` to display. [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) modifies an existing `Graphics` object, by either combining multiple ones together and/or modifying the options. Second, generally when declaring a function, you want to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) not `Set` (`=`), c.f. this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/52).

```
V[x_] := (1 (1 - E^(-9.8 x)))
```

`Set` is useful when you need to capture a long calculation, but usually `SetDelayed` captures the idea of what a function is better. Third, in your argument to `Plot` you multiply `V[x]` by `(1 (1 - E^(-9.8 x)))`, or `V[x]`, which I do not think is what you intend.

All together,

```
Plot[V[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]
```

which is not much different than your original plot (not shown).